# Dismissing Webview crashes app

Tags: ios, webview

The mobile app I'm working on loads a webview viewcontroller which opens a URL defined in the sqlite database of the application and streams the video content to a player within the app.

The video loads and plays properly but it crashes whenever I attempt to dismiss the view.

The relevant obj-c code is:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil gscreenvid:(NSString *)url {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        gscreenvid = url;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (gscreenvid != nil && [gscreenvid compare:@""] != 0) {
        NSURL *p_url = [NSURL URLWithString:gscreenvid];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:p_url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
}

- (IBAction) cancelButtonTapped:(id) sender {
    [self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem I added these lines to viewDidLoad

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:) name:@"MPAVControllerItemPlaybackDidEndNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerWillExitFullscreen) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
}
```

and

```
- (void)playerWillExitFullscreen {
    [self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"done");
}

- (void)playbackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"note.name=%@ state=%d", note.name, [[note.userInfo
    objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue]);
    [self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line below

`[self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Should be

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem.  Still zooms to black and freezes.

Comment: After reading your question more you should really be using the MediaPlayer framework to play video from a URL. Not sure if Vimeo will have like a html 5 URL to just the video not the video page. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController